# Combining ride data from Wahoo & Fitbit, on Strava

Tags: strava

Similar to [How can I combine Garmin recorded track data with FitBit heart rate data?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/56338/how-can-i-combine-garmin-recorded-track-data-with-fitbit-heart-rate-data)

I have a Wahoo SC Blue to track speed and cadence and use the Wahoo app to log my ride (it has a nice dashboard). The completed workout gets synced to Strava. I also have a Fitbit Versa 2, but I don't log the ride on the watch as if I did, I'd end up with 2 activities on Strava.

What I'd like to do is use the heart rate data from the Fitbit, and 'inject' it into the Wahoo logged workout that appears in Strava.

I guess what I'm looking for is some sort of activity merge feature on Strava, where I can take the GPS, speed and cadence data from Wahoo, and overlay the HR data from the Fitbit based on the timestamp. Is this possible? Or am I into the realms of exporting `TCX`/`CSV` data from separate sources, and re-uploading the data to Strava?

**Update**

I'm not sure Fitbit allow a detailed enough export to make this work, if I export the activity to a `TCX` file I only see this

```
<TrainingCenterDatabase xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2">
    <Activities>
        <Activity Sport="Biking">
            <Id>2021-09-17T06:13:46.000+01:00</Id>
        </Activity>
    </Activities>
</TrainingCenterDatabase>
```

If I export data from https://www.fitbit.com/settings/data/export, then HR data isn't even included.

Comment: What you describe is one of the many useful features that Strava could have added over the years if they hadn't been so busy trying to become facebook 2.0

Comment: @AndyP at some point Strava decided to allow others to use their API and add features at no cost to them.  With the subscription changes a year or two ago, they broke some of that, but I believe the OP is in luck here

Comment: I don’t think you can with Fitbit is the short answer, however if you had a garmin watch and garmin head unit you could use extended view mode and that would send your garmin hr over.

Comment: It's been a while since I looked into this. Fitbit really doesn't want to share their data outside their walled garden. There are iPhone apps that can extract Fitbit data (perhaps Android too), but it's a fair amount of fooling around. Heart-rate chest bands are pretty cheap.

Comment: @AdamRice I'm thinking I might get a Wahoo Trakr HR band and use that instead.

Answer (score 4):

[Gotoes](https://gotoes.org/strava/Combine_GPX_TCX_FIT_Files.php) says it can do this.

Quoting from their help:

> This tool will allow you to take GPX, TCX, or FIT files and combine them into one single file for upload to Strava. There are two ways that people commonly combine files. The first is if their GPS dies during a ride... The other thing this tool can do is combine overlapping files. *For example, a user has a Wahoo device that records heart rate, and TCX output from their indoor trainer. Both devices record at the same time, but the user wants to merge the heart rate data with the ride data. This tool can do that too!* Just select the stream you want from each file. [emphasis mine]

I don't have a pair of recordings from two data sources to test this, lacking a (recording) HRM, cadence sensor etc.

You can grab your GPX data (or FIT, possibly TCX) from Strava's activity page, at least on desktop:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a go and feedback.

Comment: Sigh. You have to subscribe to Strava to download the `GPX` file.

Comment: Oh, and the `TCX` file only has a timestamp, no minute-by-minute HR data, so that's pointless.

Comment: You should be able to get the GPX directly from the Wahoo (or a format you can convert to GPX; I get GPXs off my phone and don't use a Wahoo so I'm not up to date).  It's generally easiest to get things right then upload to Strava. I often record several GPXs and merge before a single upload, either in the app on my phone or manually. Are you saying the TCX doesn't have the HR data at all?  I wouldn't mind a look at the files - if this isn't easily possible it should be.  We have 2 xml files and I'm used to dealing with those in Python.

Comment: @spikey_richie no - there's a "export GPX" , "export TCX" and "export original" in the ... menu on any strava activity.

Comment: I don't get "export TCX" just GPX and original - but they work as a non-subscriber.  I'll edit that into the answer.

Comment: Ah ha, it was snuck away on the left hand menu. Thanks.

Comment: "Are you saying the TCX doesn't have the HR data at all?" I've updated my question.

Comment: Ah. If your TCX is empty, you're not going to get very far. [Untested possible solution](https://www.squashleagues.org/fitbit/fitbitdatadownload) - but it gives you a spreadsheet not a TCX.  While I can borrow a fitbit, it's a basic one without heart rate data